# Full Text Search not indexing all the words in .msg files

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I want to ask you whether in Full Text Search the email documents (with .msg extension) fail to have all their words indexed. I came across this scenario where a particular email that was uploaded in database using FileStream contains 2000 words but the Full Text Search indexed just 400 words.

I have also tried to Rebuild the Index but that didn't include the other words in the index.'

Do you know why this might happen ?  Thanks

Comment: Does your full text catalog use a stop list? If so, it will prevent common words (the, and, of, etc.) from being indexed.

Comment: Hi keith, no, the Full-Text catalog does not use a stop list.